Data Not Showing in RecyclerView on Android Studio Emulator
I’m working on an Android app where I’m trying to display data in a RecyclerView. The data is fetched from a local database and should be displayed in the RecyclerView, but it’s not showing up in the emulator. Here is my code:
tclass HomeActivity : BaseActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding

    var arrMainCategory = ArrayList<CategoryItems>()
    var arrSubCategory = ArrayList<Recipes>()

    var mainCategoryAdapter = MainCategoryAdapter()
    var subCategoryAdapter = SubCategoryAdapter()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        enableEdgeToEdge()

        binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        getDataFromDb()

        arrSubCategory.add(Recipes(1, "Meatloaf"))
        arrSubCategory.add(Recipes(2, "Chicken and Rice"))
        arrSubCategory.add(Recipes(3, "Chocolate Cake"))
        arrSubCategory.add(Recipes(4, "Iced Tea"))

        subCategoryAdapter.setData(arrSubCategory)

        binding.rvSubCategory.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@HomeActivity,
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        binding.rvSubCategory.adapter = subCategoryAdapter

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }

    private fun getDataFromDb() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                val cat = RecipeDatabase.getDatabase(this@HomeActivity).recipeDao().getAllCategory()
                arrMainCategory = cat.toCollection(ArrayList())
                Log.d("HomeActivity", "Data fetched from database: $arrMainCategory") // Log the fetched data
                withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    mainCategoryAdapter.setData(arrMainCategory)
                    binding.rvMainCategory.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@HomeActivity,
                        LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
                    binding.rvMainCategory.adapter = mainCategoryAdapter
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("HomeActivity", "Error fetching data from database", e) // Log any errors
            }
        }
    }
}ype here

class MainCategoryAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<MainCategoryAdapter.RecipeViewHolder>() {

    var arrMainCategory = ArrayList<CategoryItems>()
    var ctx: Context? = null
    var listener: AdapterView.OnItemClickListener? = null

    class RecipeViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val tvDishName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_dish_name)
        val imgDishName: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_dish)
    }

    fun setData(arrData: ArrayList<CategoryItems>) {
        arrMainCategory = arrData as ArrayList<CategoryItems>
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecipeViewHolder {
        return RecipeViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_rv_main_category, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrMainCategory.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecipeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.tvDishName.text = arrMainCategory[position].strcategory
    }
}

I’ve added logging statements, and the data seems to be fetched correctly from the database, but it’s not being displayed in the RecyclerView. Here are the logs:
D/HomeActivity: Data fetched from database: [CategoryItems(...)]
D/HomeActivity: Data set in adapter: 4
I’ve checked that the RecyclerView and adapter are properly initialized. What could be causing this issue?


try initializing the adapter in onCreate it will make the adapter to be initialize on single thead

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    binding.rvMainCategory.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
        this@HomeActivity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false
    )
    binding.rvMainCategory.adapter = mainCategoryAdapter

    getDataFromDb()
}

